# iOS 5 Json and utf8 problems

Tags: ios, json, utf-8

I use the iOS 5 JSON features to load data from web.
My target is to get some twitter data - the data is filtered via web and I get it via the following url:
http://botpwn.org/ios/getfollowers.json?uid=63964843

Thats working and I dont have problems there - but my problems begin with parsing the data in my app.

I load the data here

```
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
                  NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://botpwn.org/ios/getfollowers.json?uid=%@", my_uid]]];
          [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) 
                                 withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
      });

  -(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
      NSError* error;
      NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                            JSONObjectWithData:responseData                        
                            options:kNilOptions 
                            error:&error];

      latestFollower = [json objectForKey:@"followers"]; //2    

      for (int i = 0; i < [latestFollower count]; i++){
          [temp addObject:[latestFollower objectAtIndex:i]];

      }

      if (latestFollower == nil || latestFollower.count == 0){
          NSLog(@"No followers");
      }
  }
```

And now I always get the answer that I have an empty latestFollower array - and I know that the problem is, that some names (not screennames) of twitter users contain special chars and iOS can't parse it.

I searched for solutions (set the php header to utf8 etc.) but nothing helps.

Maybe you have an idea how to parse it right, or maybe I'm doing something wrong but i don't get it.

EDIT: Just fixed it myself - finally I used a tool (http://jsonlint.com/) to check whether there is an error in the json output and yes - it was. Thanks for your ideas ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it myself - finally I used a tool (http://jsonlint.com/) to check whether there is an error in the json output and yes - it was. Thanks for your ideas ! :)